# Laravel collective add PHP variable to input type number

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

I am trying to add a PHP variable to an input type number, as the maximum value allowed in this field. I am using Laravel collective.

My input syntax:

```
{!! Form::number('credit_amount', '0.00', ['step' => '0.01', 'min' => '0.01', 'max' => '{{ $creditBalance }}', 'class' => 'text-center form-control']) !!}
```

I want the $creditBalance placed against the "max" attribute of the number input. I can do this without Laravel Collective, but how to do it with LC? Thanks!

Comment: You should remove '{{ and }}' from the max attribute, as this is parsed in plain PHP, not a blade-powered value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blade essentially just replaces `{!!` and `!!}` with `<?php echo` and `?>` respectively, so you can use normal PHP code:

```
{!! Form::number('credit_amount', '0.00', ['min' => '0.01', 'max' => $creditBalance, 'class' => 'text-center form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: Hi @Thomas, this resolves OK, but the input field now does not span 100% width per its CSS. Without this parameter & its PHP var, input spans 100% of container width. Why do you think?

Comment: Your CSS seems to be wrongly applied or is being overwritten. Try the browser dev tools.

Comment: checked but it looks ok. I am using default Bootstrap CSS. Interestingly, if I write the HTML directly with the PHP var is the same result, screws CSS. I take the MAX attribute out, and it all shows up perfectly.

Comment: I changed `step = "0.01"` to `step = "any"` and it works now